# from dajax.core import Dajax gives cannot import name simplejson error

Tags: ajax, django, dajax

When I run

```
from dajax.core import Dajax
```

It gives

```
cannot import name simplejson
```

Whats the fix?

I have installed dajax libraries along with django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajax/issues/69). Simplejson is deprecated in django 1.7 so Dajax is outdated.

Switch to django 1.6 or to [django-dajax-ng](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-dajax-ng).